# Failure: This torrent is not registered with this tracker

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I'm trying to hop on a torrent that I know has activity, because different websites show that there are seeders and leechers.  However, in utorrent I can't download anything or connect to anyone.  Under the Trackers tab it has the following message:

> Failure: This torrent is not
>   registered with this tracker

How can I connect to other people on this torrent so I can start downloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tracker saved in the torrent file has stopped accepting connections for that torrent.

You need to (somehow) find another tracker, and set that in utorrent.

If utorrent does not allow you to do this (I think it does), you can edit the torrent file with a torrent editor or any editor that reads BEncoding. 
You can find such an application and further information in [this utorrent forum post](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?pid=288182).

Comment: utorrent allows you to add more trackers. Right click on the trackers tab.
There's a good chance the openbittorrent tracker is mirroring it too. http://openbittorrent.com/.
Once you are connected, PEX should give you more sources.