# How do I find torrents which are no longer registered on the tracker?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

When a particular torrent is removed from the tracker, I can see that if I open the "Properties" dialog and look a the "Trackers" tab in Transmission: there is an [error message](https://superuser.com/questions/95388/failure-this-torrent-is-not-registered-with-this-tracker) saying it is "not registered".

However, this apparently is [not an error](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/issues/161), so the torrent status is still displayed as "Seeding"/"Downloading".

Is there a way to display a list of torrents without a single active tracker? I'd prefer to keep using Transmission, if possible.

Comment: A torrent has a tracker-substitute when it has none, since then it uses DHT. See [Mainline DHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainline_DHT). If you wait long enough, the network will find sources even without any official tracker.

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Removing dead torrents?

Comment: @DanielB: There are no dead torrents, so long as DHT can find a source.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, removing "dead" torrents or replacing them with new ones. In some projects (e.g. Armbian) a torrent no longer registered on the tracker means you are seeding an outdated release, which is a disservice - users will get it via DHT, install the SW, and then come to the forum asking about issues which have already been resolved.

Comment: @harrymc Indeed, such torrents are still active without any tracker. The point is, I don't want to seed them even if it is technically possible.

Comment: I'm using qBittorrent which has a Tracker column that can be sorted upon, so I can do it easily. Perhaps Transmission has the same. If not, then other Transmission interfaces might include more data: [Shift](https://github.com/killemov/Shift) or [Transmission Remote GUI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/transgui/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for in the [Transmission Remote GUI](https://github.com/transmission-remote-gui/transgui/) interface. It shows torrents without a tracker in both "Completed" and "Error" lists, and unlike the "Completed" list, the "Error" list is typically very small *and* requires manual intervention anyway.

[Shift](https://github.com/mobal/shift) GUI doesn't support sorting by active trackers out of the box, but the devs were kind enough to  [explain](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=12555&p=80202&sid=8842176a848dd299fe0e7efaedee24a2#p80202) to me how such support could be added with a bit of JS programming. Unfortunately I don't have time for this right now, but it could be a hint for someone who must stick to a browser-based GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The client I'm using is qBittorrent, which has a Tracker column that can be
displayed by right-clicking the column headers and placing a check-mark
next to "Tracker". The Tracker column is empty when there are no trackers,
and can also be sorted by value so as to bring together all the
blank fields, for easy delete.

I don't use Transmission, but perhaps it has a similar column.

If it does not, then other Transmission interfaces might include this
data: [Shift](https://github.com/killemov/Shift) or [Transmission Remote GUI](https://sourceforge.net/projects/transgui/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into the alternative Transmission GUIs.

Comment: Have you seen this feature (sorting by tracker) in Shift / TransGUI or was it an assumption? I don't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: I have it in qBittorrent. I'm not using Transmission.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The point needs to be clarified in question. You want to cancel your seeds.  In completed list> Select all and stop. Works well in uTorrent 2.2.1
Confirmed using TCP-UDP endpointer viewer from Sysinternals.

> The point is, I don't want to seed them even if it is technically possible. – Dmitry Grigoryev yesterday

*(but that puts you in the leech category)*

### Update

It is impossible to get a complete list from a tracker. A seed may disappear and have its IP removed from the tracker before the tracker hands out its IP to everyone or you only get a portion of the list.

The list is not instant real-time either, so many are transient.

Comment: I know how to stop torrents, of course. The question is more about finding torrents which were removed from the tracker.

Comment: Maybe use http://torrentspy.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score -2):

When uploading your torrent / Using Torrent Creator use the "Private Torrent" option.
It wont distribute on networks and you can still grab magnet

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: These are not my torrents I'm seeding.